# start screen programm with crontab @reboot

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, cron

I try to start a start.sh at reboot with crontab. But nothing happens afer a reboot, and the log is without an error. Does someone know what i've done wrong?
For testing i gave the start.sh and Mod.jar the 777 permission but still nothing after a reboot. If I start the start.sh manually logged in as otto, everything is ok and the Mod.jar starts after the 60 seconds.

Content of crontab -e (as User Otto)

```
@reboot               ./home/otto/server/start.sh
```

Content of the start.sh

```
sleep 60
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S mod java -mx100M -jar /home/otto/server/Mod.jar
```

The Cron log is without an error.

```
May  1 12:12:02 srv1 /USR/SBIN/CRON[1881]: (otto) CMD (./home/otto/server/start.sh)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a username 'otto' to your cron entry?  @reboot otto ./home/otto/server/start.sh ?

Comment: Not yet, i thought he know the username automatically because the cron was made as user otto and not root. But i'll try it, just one second ... Still the same problem.

Comment: **./home/otto/server/start.sh** -> **/home/otto/server/start.sh** .  Does your machine shut down before 60 seconds elapse?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AU !

This seems to be a case of display (or `stdout`) not being correctly identified by yr user's cron environment (as is normally the case for all gui applications).
You will find a lot of Q/A on that subject in AU and StackExchange at large.

Solution:
In user `otto`'s crontab, modify yr job entry for it to read:

```
@reboot   DISPLAY=:0 /home/otto/server/start.sh
```

Note;
I suppressed the spurious `.` in front of your fully qualified script invocation. Absolute paths are needed in scripts or programs being invoked by cron; they always start with a `/`.